# Edit Button for JTable to edit Database contents Produce

Tags: mysql, netbeans, jtable, edit

[The Error]

Hello there i'm new to Netbean and currently designing a warehouse database. I seem to have a problem with my coding and the error appears as the image stated above / ....Corresponds to your MYSQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where WarehouseID='1331' at line 1. Does anyone has a better coding for this ? am i mistaken somewhere? I'm using MYSQL WorkBench 6.3. here is my coding :

```
           private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
         int row = tbl.getSelectedRow();
        String tableclick =(tbl.getModel().getValueAt(row,0 ).toString());
        String value1=wid.getText();
        String value2=wna.getText();
        String value3=lo.getText();
        String value4=add.getText();
        String value5=pic.getText();
        String sql="update warehouse set WarehouseID='"+value1+"', WarehouseName='"+value2+"',Location='"+value3+"',Address='"+value4+"',PersonInCharge='"+value5 + "',where WarehouseID='" + tableclick ;
          pst=conn.prepareStatement (sql ) ;
             pst.executeUpdate() ; 

      } catch (Exception e ){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null , e );
    }finally{ 
        try{ 
            pst.close(); 
            rs.close(); 
               }catch(Exception e){ 
        }      
}                                        
}
```

Comment: Re "error appears as the image stated above", I don't see any image above only text that says "[The Error]"

Comment: You have an extra comma just before the where in your string. Also it would be safer and more readable to use ? in your query and use PreparedStatement set functions to setParameters eg "update warehouse set WarehouseID=? ...", pst.setString(1,value1).

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where WarehouseID='No45' at line 1

Comment: Sorry i'm low in reputations to upload an image. i think MYSQL can't accept ?<< as in my workbench query

Comment: Whoa it works ! Thanks WillShackleford !

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma just before the where in your string. Also it would be safer and more readable to use ? in your query and use PreparedStatement set functions to setParameters eg "update warehouse set WarehouseID=? ...", pst.setString(1,value1). – WillShackleford